# SQL reports error when secondary table has no records

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, ms-access-2010

I'm writing a Family Tree application with an Access 2010 back end and VB.NET front end. (Long story, not relevant here.)
Most everything works, but I need to sort the marriages for a person.  As with sorting children in a family, we can't just use the obvious DateOfBirth or DateOfMarriage fields because we don't always have values.  Here's a simplified snapshot of my data structure

```
People Table                Families Table
- ID                        - ID
- FullName                  - Husband
- DOB (Date of Birth)       - Wife
- DOD (Date of Death)       - DOM (Date of Marriage)

PersonMarriage Table (a linking table)
- Person (foreign key to People)
- Family (foreign key to Families)
- Spouse (foreign key to People)
- Marriage Order (a contrived value to force the order we want)

FamilyChild Table (a linking table)
- Family (foreign key to Families)
- Child  (foreign key to People)
- BirthOrder (a contrived value to force the order we want)
```

(FWIW, my dates of birth, date, and marriage are contrived so that I can handle values like "March 1862" and "Before 1753" but still maintain sortability.  The empty string signifies "Unknown")

I'm trying to read relevant data about all of the marriages for a person so that I can use complex comparisons to provide a partial sort.  For instance, when a person has two marriages, and we don't know the marriage dates, if a child of spouse A was born after spouse B died, we can infer that the marriage to spouse B occurred first.

For each marriage, I want to retrieve the marriage date, the spouse's DOB, the spouse's DOD, and the DOB of the a child. (Any child; I just grab the first physical record with a birthdate.)  Here's a SQL query that works sometimes:

```
SELECT PersonMarriage.Family, PersonMarriage.Spouse, DOM, s.DOB, s.DOD,
    (SELECT TOP 1 c.DOB FROM FamilyChild 
        LEFT JOIN People c ON FamilyChild.Child=c.ID 
    WHERE c.DOB<>"" AND FamilyChild.Family=PersonMarriage.Family) as ChildDOB 
FROM Families AS f INNER JOIN 
    (PersonMarriage INNER JOIN People AS s ON PersonMarriage.Spouse = s.ID )
ON f.ID = PersonMarriage.Family 
WHERE PersonMarriage.Person=?
```

Note that I use a subquery within the field list to find the child.   I'm sure that I need to move the child-selection subquery to the FROM clause and use a LEFT JOIN, but I just haven't figured out a way to do it.  The join order, FWIW, was determined by Access's query wizard, since the join order that seemed most natural to me just didn't work.

This query appears to work only when at least one of the marriages has a child with a birth date.  When neither marriage has a child with a birth date, I get the error on the order of "This Query can return at most one result".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the error

> "At most one record can be returned by this subquery."

Your problem stems from the fact that with an ACE/Jet (Access) database a `TOP 1` query may actually return more than one row if there is a "tie" for `TOP 1`. For example given the [People] data...

```
ID  FullName  DOB         DOD
--  --------  ----------  ---
 1  Dave      1967-07-01     
 2  Gertrude  1968-03-21     
 3  Alice     after 1968     
 4  Duncan    after 1987 
 5  Ernest    after 1987     
 6  Richard   after 2003     
 7  Suzy      after 2003
```

...the query...

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [People] ORDER BY [DOB] DESC
```

...will return two rows:

```
ID  FullName  DOB         DOD
--  --------  ----------  ---
 7  Suzy      after 2003     
 6  Richard   after 2003
```

So, instead of the subquery...

```
(
    SELECT TOP 1 c.DOB 
    FROM FamilyChild LEFT JOIN People c 
            ON FamilyChild.Child=c.ID 
    WHERE c.DOB<>"" AND FamilyChild.Family=PersonMarriage.Family
) as ChildDOB
```

...try using

```
(
    SELECT MIN(c.DOB) 
    FROM FamilyChild LEFT JOIN People c 
            ON FamilyChild.Child=c.ID 
    WHERE c.DOB<>"" AND FamilyChild.Family=PersonMarriage.Family
) as ChildDOB
```